# Cordova Build Error: More than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms

Tags: cordova, admob

I am developing android application with cordova, I need google plus login and admob feature in my my app ,

So I add the following plugins

1) [admobpro](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro.git)

2) [cordova-plugin-googleplus](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus.git)

Is it necessary to add google play service plugin to use the above plugin ?

After I added Google play service plugin and build the app using cordova CLI

I got the following error,

```
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
> 
> * What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
> > Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms' You can temporarily disable this error with
> android.enforceUniquePackageName=fal se However, this is temporary and
> will be enforced in 1.0
> 
> * Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

kindly help me,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem with google play service plugin i added, google play service is also loaded as dependent plugin with googleplus login plugin, so there occurred a conflict between these two google play service plugins.
I removed all plugins and added google plus login first and then add admobpro, now i can successfully  build the app with no exception.